# How to get the coordinates of the 4 vertexes of a GeoListPlot?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, geography, geographics

I have a `GeoListPlot` as below. How can I get the latitude/longitude coordinates of the 4 vertexes of the `GeoListPlot`? I need the 4 vertexes to reconstruct the rectangle.

```
g = GeoListPlot@{
Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"SanBernardinoCounty", "California", "UnitedStates"}], 
Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"StanislausCounty", "California", "UnitedStates"}], 
Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"AlamedaCounty", "California", "UnitedStates"}]
}
```

[image]

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[g]
```

> {{-122.746, -113.724}, {35.7826, 41.5036}}

```
GeoRange /. AbsoluteOptions[g]
```

> {{33.6605, 38.2878}, {-122.746, -113.724}}

```
Show[g, Frame -> True, Epilog -> {Opacity[.25], EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[], 
 Rectangle @@ Transpose[PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[g]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure for the exact reason, but when the number of entities increase, `PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[g]` will have some errors, and `GeoRange /. AbsoluteOptions[g]` gives no error. The latter solves my problem. Many thanks!